# My AppleMacPro1,1 has 8 slots for 2x1GB memory in each

Tags: memory-management

I cannot find a replacement for 2 of them that have failed, and can only find 2x2GB ones. My question is will it be ok to put these in the 1GB slots?

Answer (score 0):

The Mac Pro 1,1 can take 32GB RAM, as 8 x 4GB sticks, but the configuration in pairs is important & less obvious than you would think.

From Apple KB : [Mac Pro (Mid 2012 and earlier): How to remove or install memory](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT205043)

> You should install FB-DIMMs in matched pairs of equal size and equal specification.
>      Use the table below and the instructions that follow as guidelines for DIMM placement.
>
> ```
> If you have   Install
> Two DIMMs (standard configuration) One on the top memory card and one on the bottom card
> Four DIMMs    One pair on the top memory card and one pair on the bottom card
> Six DIMMs Two pairs on the top memory card and one pair on the bottom card
> Eight DIMMs   Two pairs on the top memory card and two pairs on the bottom card
> ```

Also see Everymac : [Apple Mac Pro "Quad Core" 2.66 (Original) Specs](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_pro/specs/mac-pro-quad-2.66-specs.html) which also lists retailers in the US, UK & Australia that carry stock for that machine.